# How to decrease overall brightness of google map so that the pins are more visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I looked through this URL.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Should I change the

```
stylers: [
    { lightness: 0 }
]
```

for each featureType and elementType?

OR
Is there a better way to decrease the overall appeal of the map so that the pins on the map stand out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea. The lightness defaults at 0 so you will want to decrease it to a negative number if that is your aim. Decreasing the saturation might give more of the effect you want, but here is a good place to play with those values: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: That link is 404 - Please see google maps style demo here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling